# Searching HTML document by ID using XPATH returns wrong result

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

So, id like to get this element from line 200

```
<p id="Para">Hello, how are you.</p>
```

To do so I am using the XPATH

```
HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@id,'Para')]")
```

However, the node that is returned is not the one I am looking for and instead gets an element before it on line 10

```
<p id="ParaInstruction">Click here to begin</p>
```

I think this is because the ids have the first 4 chars in common so it gets the first one it can find. How do I ensure that the node that is returned only has the chars specified in the XPATH.

Comment: A very common mistake, using contains() without understanding what it does! Never try to guess the semantics of a function from its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
//*[contains(@id,'Para')]
```

to

```
//*[@id='Para']
```

to avoid matching every element whose `@id` *contains* a `"Para"` *substring*, which is what `contains()` does -- test for substring containment.